# Why does Laravel 5 keep redirecting to /login after authenticating user (post upgrade)

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, upgrade

I used LaraShift to upgrade my Laravel 4.2 app to 5.0. LaraShift got me about halfway there, and I've spent 10 hours getting 90+% of the remaining 50%. Where I'm completely stuck is on the login. Laravel is authenticating the user, but then immediately redirecting back to the login page. This is the top of my sessionsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\Custom\proxyPermissions;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Services\Custom\sendEmail;
use App\Site;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return view('sessions.login');
    }

    public function loginPost()
    {
        if ($t = Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'), Input::only('remember'))) {
            $u = Auth::user();

            if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
                $user = User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->with('sites')->first();
                if (isset($user->sites[0])) {
                    Site::store2Session($user->sites[0]->id);
                } else {
                    Site::store2Session(1);
                }
            }

            if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
                return Redirect::home();
            } else {
                // User is not an admin
                /*  After user logs in, control comes here, but user is redirected back to the login page
                    instead of to the intended URL or / 
                */
                return Redirect::intended('/');
                //return Redirect::intended();
                //return Redirect::intended('/')->with('flash_notice','Welcome back!');
            }
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('flash_error', 'Login Failed')->withInput();
    }
```

With the exception of the namespace and use statements at the top, this is the same code I had in 4.2. The app is getting to this line:

`return Redirect::intended('/');`

at the bottom and then redirecting to /login

The password reset function works correctly. The user is authenticating when entering the correct username & password. I have a standard user model with id, email, password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know how the application flow has changed from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0, but I did find the source of the error. In 4.2, after the user logged in, after they got redirected, their permissions were written into the session. That's not happening (in the same order) in Laravel 5.0.

I found this code put in by a previous developer:

```
// @TODO <name redacted>: TEMPORARY FIX, until all session replaced with links to get site data
if (empty($site)) {
    // if no session data, redirect user to login
    \Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```